# How to read the from AWS Active MQ queue using curl command

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, activemq-classic

How we can get the messages from AWS Active MQ queue using curl command ?

```
curl -v -u -XGET username:password 'https://hostname:8162/api/message/lte_ap_kpi_sci?type=queue'

curl -v -XGET http://username:password@hostname:8162/api/message?destination=queue://lte_ap_kpi_sci&json=true&oneShot=true
```

Used above command but wasn't able to get any messages from queue.

Please find below logs

```
lte_ap_kpi_sci'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying IP:PORT...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hostname
 (IP) port PORT (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.mq.region.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Apr 18 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: May 17 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "hostname" matched cert's "*.mq.region.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /api/message?destination=queue://lte_ap_kpi_sci HTTP/1.1
> Host: hostname:PORT
> Authorization: Basic token==
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Wed, 23 Feb 2022 18:51:08 GMT
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< Location: https://hostname:PORT/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.4.43.v20210629)
<
* Connection #0 to host hostname left intact
```

Is there any possible way to read the messages from queue using curl command ?

Comment: Does Amazon MQ even support ActiveMQ's REST interface? If not, there's no way you can use `curl` to get messages.

Comment: @JustinBertram yeah it doesn't support REST interface.

Comment: Are you actually using Amazon MQ or are you just using ActiveMQ 5.x deployed in AWS which you are managing yourself?

Comment: We are using Amazon MQ. We are trying to read data from amazon MQ using telegraf plugin. Telegraf plugin as of now only supports reading data from topics and not from queues.
So we were checking the possibility if we can read data using curl command.
As Active MQ doesn't support REST interface, we raised a feature request at telegraf to support reading data from queue as well.